# How to find all ways to obtain an integer n as the sum of m integers (without order)?

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

I'm looking for an algorithm that finds all ways to express an integer n as the sum of m (non-negative) integers. I am in particular interested in m=6 and n⩽20. What would be the fastest way to find all possibilities (using a computer, not by hand). If possible, I would like to only look at combinations of six integers, with order not being relevant (that is, [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] and [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] are counted as 1 combination).

The simplest way would be simply trying all permutations with 6 integers lesser than or equal to 20 and only adding the ones that sum up to 20 to our result (followed by removing doubles if we do not want to look at the ordering). This seems like it would take awfully long however, since 20^6 possibilities will take quite a while to check.

What would be a more efficient way to tackle this?

Comment: Hint: Avoiding repetitions can be done easily if you generate them in sorted order. If you have m numbers to fill so that they sum up to n and the numbers are in increasing order, what are the possibilities for the first number?

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid repetitions by generating the numbers in monotonically increasing order (each number is equal to or greater than the previous one).

For a given `count` (e.g. 6), you can define the problem recursively by generating all the possible values for the first number and then recursively generating all the lists of `count - 1` numbers that sum to the original sum minus the first number, with the first number being the minimum value for the remaining numbers in the list.

Because the numbers need to be increasing, you can't "peak too early" - you can calculate a maximum value by dividing the sum by the count (since all remaining values will have to be equal to or greater than this).

Here is a simple implementation in Java:

```
public static void outputSums(String start, int sum, int count, int min)
{
    // if there is just one value, it's just the sum:
    if(count == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(start + " " + sum);
        return;
    }

    int max = sum / count;  // calculate maximum value
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        outputSums(start + " " + i,  // append each number to the list
            sum - i,  // recursively find numbers that sum to the remainder
            count - 1,   // with a count of one less
            i);   // equal to or greater to this one (i.e. increasing order)
    }
}
```

`start` contains the partial list that you have output so far. It will be empty when you first call the function.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/INWfZX)

Answer (score 2):

The converse of the previous approach is to calculate it from largest to smallest.

Here is a Python implementation of that, using iterators so that it is easy to use programmatically.

```
def partition (count, total, maximum = None) :
    if maximum is None or total < maximum:
        maximum = total
    if 0 == count:
        yield []
    else:
        while total <= count * maximum:
            for part in partition(count - 1, total - maximum, maximum):
                yield part + [maximum]
            maximum = maximum - 1
```

And here is an example of how to use it programmatically to print your output:

```
for part in partition(6, 10):
    print(part)
```